# Downloading Audio Files from Watson text-to-speech

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson, watson-text-to-speech

Trying to figure out how to simply download audio files from Watson's text-to-speech.
Supposedly there used to be a download button but there isn't anymore. Is there an easy way to download audio files? The documentation seems complicated and we do not need to use it for a site.

Thank you,
Ashley

Answer (score 0):

From the API Documentation
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech#synthesize-audio-get

You can use cURL :

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "{url}/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=Hello%20world&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"
```